# Sums of points per date grouped by additional column in a form of a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, pivot-table

I would like to obtain sum of points of some technologies per date from pandas data frame. A reproducible example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'date': ['2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-02-28'],
        'tech': [['c++', 'python'], ['c++', 'c', 'java'], ['java']],
        'score': [1, 4, 2]}
        )
```

The end result could look like this (or have the names in rows and one column with counts per date and technology):

```
date        c++     python  c   java
2017-01-31  1       1       4   0
2017-02-28  4       0       4   6
```

Points (the column `score`) should be summed per date and technology. The solution of grouping by date and technology is not possible since each row can contain multiple programming languages/frameworks. I wrote the following code:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'tech': data[['tech']].values.tolist(),
               'score': data['score'].values,
               'date': data['date'].values}).groupby(['date','tech']))['score'].sum()
```

which produces an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

so I presume that grouping by list is not possible. I am aware that the above given idea does not split the data by technology, however, I don't know how to do this with the column `score` (or even multiple columns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert your original data to this format

```
s=data.tech.str.len()
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'date':data.date.repeat(s),'score':data.score.repeat(s),'tech':np.concatenate(data.tech.values)})
newdf
Out[477]: 
         date  score    tech
0  2017-01-31      1     c++
0  2017-01-31      1  python
1  2017-02-28      4     c++
1  2017-02-28      4       c
1  2017-02-28      4    java
2  2017-02-28      2    java
```

Then, we using `pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(newdf,index='date',columns='tech',values='score',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
Out[476]: 
tech        c  c++  java  python
date                            
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  4    4     6       0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, I don't understand why the `tech` column should be concatenated. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: this is so called unesting , with object (list) item , it is hard to do with the calculation @kaksat

Comment: I was wondering for a while how Python _knows_ that a given string is related to the corresponding date and score, and then I saw that each date and score are repeated the _s_ number of times, where _s_ is the number of strings in a list. Clever!

Comment: @kaksat yw you got it

Answer (score 4):

Magic with `get_dummies` and `sum`.

```
(data.tech
     .str.join(' ')
     .str.get_dummies(sep=' ')
     .mul(data.score.values, axis=0)
     .set_index(data.date)
     .sum(level=0)
)

            c  c++  java  python
date                            
2017-01-31  0    1     0       1
2017-02-28  4    4     6       0
```

Just ensure your language names don't themselves contain spaces, or else you'll need to change `sep=' '` from a whitespace to something else (that isn't found in any of your languages' names).